# Image not found in Visual Editor MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

We're using the Visual Editor (version 0.1.0 (c947b49) 9 jul 2015) with MW 1.25.3 and have a problem with the images. Images are shown correctly in read-mode but not when editing a page with the VE.

If I use Inspect Element in the browser with an image I see an incorrect path:

For instance image with  `src="/wiki/hzportfolio/images/e/e8/SSM_process_v_20151107.jpeg"` shows `localhost/wiki/hzportfolio/images/e/e8/SSM_process_v_20151107.jpeg` which of course cannot be found.

How do I configure imagepaths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: I had to set [$wgServer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer), now it's working correctly.